# Quantitative version of Lévy's continuity theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

[Lévy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%99s_continuity_theorem) implies that if the sequence of characteristic functions $(\varphi_n)_n$ of a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_n$ converges pointwise to the characteristic function $\varphi$ of some random variable $X$, then $X_n$ [converges in distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) to $X$.

Is there a quantitative version of this statement in the form of an upper bound on the the pointwise distance between the corresponding distribution functions $F_n$ and $F$ in terms of some distance between $\varphi_n$ and $\varphi$?

Continuity of $F$ can be assumed.